# Windows Printer - Save To File adding whitespace to text files?

Tags: windows, printers

I am not sure if I just don't understand the function of the save to file for a printer, or if Windows is just being whack. I have a generic local printer setup with a FILE port set. When I go to print a basic .txt file it adds whitespace to the text file as if to mimic the page margins? All I want is for the printer to save AN EXACT copy of the text file, with no additional whitespace/margins added. This is because I will be using mfilemon to dynamically create the filenames to be processed by a service. I read a few forums that mention setting the printer page sizes/margin, but when I am in in the printer properties I only have a dropdown of page sizes, with no options to change anything specific, presumably due to the driver being set as Generic/Text Only. See below an example:

The source .txt file
[source text file with no whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7p5O.png)

The saved text file, with magical whitespace added to it from the printer...
[whitespace added to presumably mimic page margins?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKkDx.png)

Comment: If you want an exact copy, why bother with printing to file? Why not create a copy with a *.prn extension?

Comment: And how would that be achieved via a printer? My constraint is we are receiving print jobs from an external source and have ZERO control that part.

Comment: That's an important detail. Please add this to your question.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or is it about setting up a printer? If it's the latter, your question would probably get more traction on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com).